# How I delete a shape at the format Label with Tag and Text

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have a format with the Label, Tag, and text into a shape, so, I want to delete a shape with the double click, it was functioning for the sample shape with, a circle, rect, and so on, but the shape Label, Tag and text, I can´t delete with double click at once. The problem is when I have 20 shapes (Label, Tag, and text), só I need 40 double clicks to delete all.

Code

```
var numberLabel = new Konva.Label({
    x: width / 2,
    y: 30,
    id: 'cNumberLabel',
    draggable: true,
});

numberLabel.add(new Konva.Tag({
    fill: bgCollor,
    stroke: 'black',
    lineJoin: 'round',
    pointerDirection: direction,
    pointerWidth: 8,
    pointerHeight: 11,
    cornerRadius: 2,
    draggable: false,
}));

var textNode = new Konva.Text({
    text: '',
    fontSize: 15,
    draggable: false,
    align: 'center',
    width: 22,
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    id: 'cTextNodecNumberLabel',
});

numberLabel.add(textNode);
layerDraw.add(numberLabel);

textNode.on('dragend click', (e) => {
    textNode.hide();

    var textPosition = textNode.absolutePosition();

    var areaPosition = {
        x: stageDraw.container().offsetLeft + textPosition.x,
        y: stageDraw.container().offsetTop + textPosition.y,
    };

    var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);

    textarea.value                 = textNode.text();
    textarea.style.position        = 'absolute';
    textarea.style.top             = areaPosition.y + 'px';
    textarea.style.left            = areaPosition.x + 'px';
    textarea.style.width           = textNode.width() - textNode.padding() * 2 + 'px';
    textarea.style.height          = textNode.height() - textNode.padding() * 2 + 5 + 'px';
    textarea.style.fontSize        = textNode.fontSize() + 'px';
    textarea.style.border          = 'none';
    textarea.style.padding         = '0px';
    textarea.style.margin          = '0px';
    textarea.style.overflow        = 'hidden';
    textarea.style.background      = 'none';
    textarea.style.outline         = 'none';
    textarea.style.resize          = 'none';
    textarea.style.lineHeight      = textNode.lineHeight();
    textarea.style.fontFamily      = textNode.fontFamily();
    textarea.style.transformOrigin = 'left top';
    textarea.style.textAlign       = textNode.align();
    textarea.style.color           = textNode.fill();

    rotation = textNode.rotation();
    var transform = '';

    if (rotation) {
        transform += 'rotateZ(' + rotation + 'deg)';
    }

    var px = 0;
    var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
    
    if (isFirefox) {
        px += 2 + Math.round(textNode.fontSize() / 20);
    }

    transform += 'translateY(-' + px + 'px)';
    textarea.style.transform = transform;
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 3 + 'px';
    textarea.focus();

    function removeTextarea() {
        textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
        window.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
        textNode.show();
    }

    function setTextareaWidth(newWidth) {
        if (!newWidth) {
            newWidth = textNode.placeholder.length * textNode.fontSize();
        }
        
        var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
        
        if (isSafari || isFirefox) {
            newWidth = Math.ceil(newWidth);
        }

        var isEdge = document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent);
        if (isEdge) {
            newWidth += 1;
        }
        textarea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
    }

    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            textNode.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            removeTextarea();
        }
    });

    textarea.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        textNode.text(textarea.value);
        removeTextarea();
    });

    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        scale = textNode.getAbsoluteScale().x;
        setTextareaWidth(textNode.width() * scale);
        textarea.style.height = 'auto';
        textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + textNode.fontSize() + 'px';
    });

    function handleOutsideClick(e) {
        if (e.target !== textarea) {
            textNode.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
    });
});

textNode.on('mouseover', function () {
    stageDraw.container().style.cursor = "pointer";
});

textNode.on("mouseleave", function() {
    stageDraw.container().style.cursor = "default";
});


stageDraw.on('dblclick dbltap', function (e) {

    if (e.target === stageDraw) {
        return;
    }

    let currentShape = e.target;

    currentShape.remove();
    currentShape.destroy();

    layerDraw.draw();
    generateJsonLayout();
});
```

Comment: Please update the question to include enough code to reproduce the problem.  It's not possible to run the posted code as there are many undefined  variables.  The html would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
stageDraw.on('dblclick dbltap', function (e) {

    if (e.target === stageDraw) {
        return;
    }
    
    // check if clicked shape is inside label
    if (e.target.getParent() instanceOf Konva.Label) {
      e.target.getParent().destroy();
    } else {
      e.target.destroy();
    }
    layerDraw.draw();
    generateJsonLayout();
});
```